# XAMPP SSL Certificado no válido en red

Tags: xampp, ssl, certificado-ssl

He instalado y configurado XAMPP en linux como servidor web para desarrollo y accesible por los equipos en red. He configurado httpd-vhost y demás archivos para poder hacer uso de SSL y navegación https. Siguiendo estas [instrucciones](https://luvunix.wordpress.com/2019/02/02/generating-self-signed-certificate-in-xampp-apache-web-server-windows-linux/) he generado los certificados correspondientes y los he añadido xampp. En modo local, en el propio linux (Centos 7), navega bien mediante https, pero los equipos en red en windows me dan un error de certificado no válido al navegar en las páginas a pesar de haberles instalado el certificado (.crt) en el sistema como Entidad de Autorización en Firefox. ¿Tendría que generar otro tipo de certificado? ¿Como puedo completarlo para poder navegar por https en la red sobre xampp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tengo una serie de pasos que quizás te resuelva el problema con el certificado SSL. 
Puede que sea por que tu certificado no tiene nombre alternativo.

CREAR CERTIFICADO AUTOFIRMADO VÁLIDO

CONFIGURAR ARCHIVO openssl.cnf
ir a la ruta

```
cd C:\xampp\apache\conf\
```

abrir ARCHIVO openssl.cnf

DENTRO DEL ARCHIVO DESCOMENTAR Y MODIFICAR VARIABLE req_extensions

```
req_extensions = req_ext
```

AÑADIR AL FINAL DEL ARCHIVO

```
[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = tudominio
DNS.2 = tudominio.com
```

Nota:
tudominio -> aquí iría tu nombre de dominio en cuestión.

IR A DIRECTORIO APACHE DONDE ESTÁ EL ARCHIVO OPENSSL

```
cd C:\xampp\apache\bin
```

ESTANDO EN ESTE DIRECTORIO EJECUTAMOS LOS SIGUIENTES COMANDOS PARA CREAR EL CERTIFICADO

GENERAR CLAVE PRIVADA

```
openssl genrsa -out C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\local.key 4096
```

GENERAR CSR

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -out C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.csr\local.csr -key C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\local.key -config C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf
```

CREAR CERTIFICADO, CRT

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 3650 -in C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.csr\local.csr -signkey  C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\local.key -out  C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\local.crt -extensions req_ext -extfile C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf
```

YA TIENES TU CERTIFICADO AUTOFIRMADO CREADO

Comment: Gracias. He seguido estos pasados y crea el certificado correctamente. Lo he configurado en apache y funciona, pero el navegador sigue diciendo que el certificado no es válido a pesar de haberlo instalado como "entidades de certificación de raíz de confianza". Si muestro información del certificado me dice que es correcto, pero chrome sigue diciendo que no es seguro.

Comment: ¿Tienes certificados autofirmados, duplicados en entidades de certificación de raíz de confianza? Si es así borra todos los duplicados.

Comment: No. Lo acabo de comprobar. No hay duplicados. Según el error que muestra Firefox y google es que no admiten certificados autofirmados.

Comment: ¿Lo añadiste desde el navegador Google Chrome? A mi el certificado autofirmado me funciona, hay que mirar que puede ser.

Comment: Si, lo he probado en el propio Linux en local en Firefox, y en un equipo de la red con Windows 10 en Chrome y en Firefox. En los tres da el mismo mensaje de error. Añades la excepción y funciona por https, pero claro te indica que no es seguro.

Comment: Solucionado. Lo había añadido al almacen que no era. Ahora ya está solucionado y efectivamente ahora si da conexión seguro y me funciona también Advanced Rest Client. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.